# Python: For Loop to iterate through two lists

Tags: python-2.7

I need to iterate through a place ID, add the people in the personID list, then move on to the next place ID and add the same list of people to that place.  Below is the snippet I have so far. I added the "for place in placeID:", but am unsure what else needs to be added after that.  I'm a novice, so please forgive me if this is super simple.

```
placeID = [12345,23456]
print placeID
personID = [123,234,345,456]
print personID

for place in placeID:

    for person in personID:
        uri = "/places/{}".format(placeID)
        base_url = "https://example.url.com"
        url = base_url + uri
        ...
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather unclear, but I believe this is what you want:

```
uri = "/places/{}".format(place)
```

`placeID` is the list containing places, and if you're trying to generate a URL for each item in `placeID`, you need to use `place` instead.